# Making a modern-looking message-list in Qt?

Tags: python-3.x, qt, qt-designer, pyside6

I am trying to make a chat application.

I have a QListView widget which I want to fill with messages. I want to make the application look like modern chats (Messenger, Instagram, etc).

**More details**:
I want the messages to be able to stick to each side of the widget and maybe add some rounding on the borders.

**Example in HTML/CSS**:

```css
.message-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20rem;
  background: red;
}

.line {
  display: block;
}

.message {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 3rem;
  line-height: 3rem;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
  padding: 0 1rem;
  background: green;
}

.right {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="message-container">
      <div class="line"><div class="message">Hello</div></div>
      <div class="line"><div class="message right">Hello friend!</div></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

1. Is QListView helpful for this job?
2. What is the best way to achieve something like that?

**NOTES**:
I though a way would be using frames but I feel like I'm thinking a lot in HTML terms. I have made some Qt GUI in the past, but it's the first time trying to decorate it.

Comment: You could actually use HTML hosted within a qtextbrowser or qwebview

Comment: Is that so? But wouldn't that be really slow compared to simple QWidgets? (I care about the performance if possible)

Comment: Perhaps QML would suit your needs better, it's easier to design modern and responsive UIs in that QWidgets

Comment: Isn't QML a way to use QWidgets? Can't the same be done in Qt Designer?

Comment: @user18812922 No, even if they share common aspects QML and QWidgets are very different. It is possible to use/show QML in a QWidget based app (through QQuickWidget). I wouldn't suggest directly using HTML for QTextBrowser/QTextEdit, as the source HTML is never stored and it uses the QTextDocument interface instead, which *may* be a possibility, but won't probably be effective on the long run. A possible alternative is to use the Graphics View framework, which may be a better choice for performance reasons. Unfortunately, questions asking for such broad "best ways" are considered off topic.